# Простое глагольное сказуемое или составное?

Tags: синтаксис

Помогите определить тип сказуемого в предложении "Я пойду погулять".

Comment: Странная логика "правильных ответов"...

Comment: Дерзкий Grantum, а где же Ваш ответ с правильной логикой?

Comment: Переезжаем на другое поле. Дуэль продолжается, но кто-то должен признать поражение. Итак, отправляюсь загорать. (Только куда, в столице нашей Родины 10 градусов условного тепла). Кроме того, до пляжа надо дойти или доехать. "Отправляюсь загорать" - это ОТПРАВЛЯЮСЬ в путь, чтобы добраться до соответствующего места. Где тут модальность? Это всего лишь сообщение о начале движения в нужном направлении. А модальность - это " я собираюсь (планирую, намереваюсь) сегодня позагорать". И учащиеся должны твердо запомнить: надо доказать, что первый глагол фазовый или модальный, тогда это СГС.

Comment: *Начинаю худеть* и *отправляюсь загорать*, не вижу в этих сочетаниях никакой разницы в плане модальности. "Это всего лишь сообщения о начале движения в нужном направлении." С помощью весьма условных терминов языкознания можно доказать любой заранее принятый тезис, не правда ли, София.

Comment: Когда знаешь ответ, уверенней себя чувствуешь, его доказывая. А где еще найти этот ответ, как не в курсе лекций по современному синтаксису для вузов за 2013 год. В заключение хочется пожелать Вам дальнейших успехов в постижении  такой сложной категории, как модальность (как в лингвистическом, так и в философском плане). Ну и хорошей погоды, конечно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это, действительно, простое глагольное сказуемое (ПГС), но его нужно отличать от сходных вариантов:

1) я пойду погулять - простое глагольное сказуемое "пойду"(ПГС), инфинитив является обстоятельством цели при глаголе движения или положения.

2) хочу (решил) погулять - составное глагольное сказуемое (СГС), вспомогательный глагол с модальным значением. (Его также называют субъектный инфинитив).

3) сказали погулять - простое глагольное сказуемое "сказали" (ПГС), объектный инфинитив "погулять" не входит в сказуемое, так действие совершают разные лица.

4)я пойду погуляю (ср. я погуляю) - простое глагольное сказуемое "пойду погуляю" (ПГС), но в осложненной форме: добавлен глагол "пойду" в личной форме, обычно со значением движения или положения.

Comment: Все верно. А как бы Вы, София, объяснили ученику разницу между первым и четвертым случаем? Ведь разница весьма условная. В обоих случаях могу задать вопрос "зачем?", и заменить на "Я погуляю" тоже можно и там, и там. Оттенок смысла трудно уловим. Логичнее было  бы 1 случай тоже считать простым осложненным сказуемым. (Кстати, такого термина в школе нет).

Comment: Мне кажется, школьникам надо как можно раньше привыкать к такому явлению, как синонимия синтаксических форм, они же понимают, что такое слова-синонимы. Мысль простая, но очень важная: одно и то же содержание можно выразить различными грамматическими формами: пойду погулять - пойду погуляю. И по поводу отсутствия понятия ОГС: а как тогда  разбираются такие сказуемые:возьму и уйду, смотри не урони,он как закричит, ждет не дождется, криком кричать?

Comment: Ларf, я  всё думаю о Ваших школьниках: как им лучше объяснить ОГС. Мне кажется, две формы можно расшифровать следующим образом: А) "Я пойду погулять" - это "я пойду на улицу, чтобы погулять (целевое значение). Б)"я пойду погуляю" -  это я пойду на улицу и там погуляю. Здесь однородные сказуемые "пойду, погуляю" представлены в виде одного осложненного сказуемого.

Comment: Спасибо.. .

Comment: *Пойду погулять* (*поеду разузнать*, *отправлюсь загорать*) - крайне спорный пример ПГС. Разве нельзя здесь рассматривать первую часть в качестве модальной?? Или фазисной))  
Жонглироввание терминами, субъективность подходов, нечеткость формулировок : отсюда споры и непонимание.

Comment: Нельзя рассматривать первую часть в качестве модальной или фазисной. Первый глагол (пойду погулять)не является вспомогательным, так как сохраняет лексическое значение движения. Разницу можно увидеть из Вашего примера: охранник пошел (начал) ругаться. (СГС) - Охранник пошел ругаться на улицу (ПГС). И никакого жонглирования. Также после фазового глагола (начало действия) основной глагол имеет несов. вид, а "погулять" - сов. вид.

Comment: *Отправлюсь загорать* - СГС? В чем отличие от *пойду погулять*? Кажется, отличий никаких нет.

Comment: Отправляюсь загорать, пойду погулять - это ПГС + обстоятельство. Отличий нет. Несов. вид основного глагола важен для фазового вспомогательного глагола в СГС, а для ПГС это не важно.

Comment: *Отправлюсь загорать*. В сочетании с инфинитивом глагол *отправлюсь* приобретает значение модального. То же самое касается и глагола ***пойду***. Имею мнение) Как быть тем учащимся, которые **могут подумать** точно так же...

Comment: Всю зыбкость различения форм иллюстрирует следующая пара примеров : *буду шуметь* (ПГС) и *начну шуметь* (СГС).

Comment: София, спасибо за Ваши комментарии.

Answer (score 2):

здесь простое глагольное сказуемое

Answer (score 2):

Это простое глагольное сказуемое.  Понятие , что в простом глагольным сказуемом должно быть одно слово - ошибочно. Оно может состоять из нескольких слов. Подробнее здесь: http://www.odnoklassniki.ru/dk?cmd=logExternal&st.cmd=logExternal&st.name=62678750789860&st.link=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.licey.net%2Frussian%2Fsyntax%2Fpart1&st._aid=FeedAltGroupMain_436_openLink

Answer (score 2):

Все дело в том, включен ли глагол ***пойти*** в список специальных глаголов, чтобы можно было считать сочетание двух форм глаголов в предложении составным глагольным сказуемым, или нет. Один из источников предлагает нам вот такой ряд :

> 1. Фазовое (начало, продолжение, конец действия)  Начать, стать, пуститься, продолжать, кончить, остаться, перестать, бросить, прекратить ***и др***.
>    Он стал готовиться к отъезду.
>    Он продолжал готовиться к отъезду.
>    Он бросил курить.
>    Он опять пустился рассуждать о тяготах сельской жизни.

http://www.licey.net/russian/syntax/r1_1_4

Чем глагол *пойти* отличается от вышеприведенных глаголов - совершенно непонятно.
*Он прекратил спорить и пошел проветриться на свежий воздух*.
*Она побежала жаловаться на декана МГУ.*

Субъективный отбор примеров в учебных пособиях (**"и др."**) порождает некоторую неразбериху в умах учащихся.

**Дополнение**.
В справочниках есть малопонятная оговорка : если спрягаемая форма глагола обозначает движение, то инфинитив не входит в состав сказуемого, а имеет целевое значение. ***Поехала*** *поступать в институт* (ПГС). Достаточно странный пункт правил. Инфинитив - это всегда цель! 
*Мечтала поступить, намеревалась поступить, решилась поступить* (СГС).
*Поехала поступать* (ПГС - ?). Невооруженным глазом во всех примерах видна цель субъекта.
Я бы лично скорректировал данный момент вот таким образом :
*Если спрягаемый глагол грамматически напрямую согласуется с инфинитивом, и обе глагольные формы относятся к одному субъекту (подлежащему), то сказуемое является составным.*
Таким образом, сочетания типа *договорился купить* и *пошел покупать* равноправно относятся к СГС.
Так гораздо проще, следовательно - лучше.

Comment: По-моему, разница очевидна: он прекратил спорить и пошел на свежий воздух, чтобы проветриться, и начал там проветриваться. В одном случае обозначена целевая установка, а в другом - начало действия. Интересно обратить внимание на разный вид глаголов.

Comment: >Ф. М. Достоевский. Братья Карамазовы (1880)  
Как приехал, так, говорят, тотчас и **пошел** {начал} **куролесить.**  
>Виктор Мясников. Водка (2000)  
Охранник Будка не вытерпел такого громкого беспорядка и **пошел** {начал} **ругаться**.

Ваш комментарий, София (СГС/ПГС).

Comment: Здесь глагол "пошел" используется не в прямом значении движения, а в переносном -  "начал". Это СГС, "пошёл" - вспомогательный фазовый глагол.

Comment: Подобным образом (переносный смысл глаголов) мы целую кучу исключений насобираем. Может, правило почетче сформулировать, дабы не было никаких сомнениий - простое или составное сказуемое? Полную таблицу вспомогательных глаголов стоит привести в справочниках...

Comment: В коллекцию примеров.  
> Максим Горький. Жизнь Клима Самгина. Часть 4 (1928-1935)  
― Я **думаю** {намереваюсь} **поехать** в Песочное, поговорить с крестьянами непосредственно, ― заявил Самгин.

ПГС или СГС? Граница размывается на глазах.

Comment: Не размывается. СГС имеет четкую теорию.В СГС грамматическое и лексическое (смысловое) значение выражено раздельно. СГС состоит из вспомогательного глагола (выражает грамматическое значение) и инфинитива(выражает лексическое значение). В роли вспомогательных глаголов могут выступать: а) фазовые глаголы; б) глаголы с модальным значением. Модальное значение: возможность, желание, намерение, решение, старание, мысли, чувства. Из этого следует, что "думаю" в данном тексте имеет модальное значение.

Comment: А можно где-нибудь полный список подобных глаголов почитать, или каждый раз **надо собирать** консилиум?

Comment: Поясните про  вид глаголов, пожалуйста.

Comment: Кажется, у модальных глаголов три основные значения: могу (возможность), хочу (желание, намерение), должен (обязанность). Вот в английском (или каком другом) языке вы же изучали модальные глаголы? Вы можете подставить эти основные глаголы, чтобы проверить значение других, например: думаю поехать - хочу поехать. Здесь нет формального решения, которое Вам предоставит справочник, но каждый случай решается по смыслу.

Answer (score 1):

Действительно, сказуемое простое. Я пойду (с какой целью?) погулять. "Погулять" будет обстоятельством.

Answer (score 0):

Я согласна с Сержем. Обе глагольные формы в сказуемом ПОЙДУ ПОГУЛЯТЬ относятся к одному суб'екту, следовательно, сказуемое составное глагольное (см. Сборник Сениной ОГЭ). А сказуемое  БУДУ ГУЛЯТЬ-  простое глагольное (глагол в форме  будущего сложного времени).